# Wait till NSTask completes its execution of terminal command

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a Cocoa application which uses NSTask to call a python script.

```
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSFileHandle *file = pipe.fileHandleForReading;
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[task setLaunchPath:@"/anaconda3/bin/python"]; // Python path
[task setArguments:@[@"run.py"]];  //My program to be executed on terminal
task.standardOutput = pipe;
task.standardError = pipe;
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];

NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
[file closeFile];

NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (@"output:\n%@", output);
```

When I try to run a small python  program like printing hello world using NSTask It gets executed. But when I try to execute a program which takes longer time(~40 seconds) to execute through NSTask, It is not executed and I am not able to get the output string from terminal.

How should I make sure my code is executed in terminal and  then the control is passed to next statements in program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add NSTask’s `waitUntilExit` method after launching the task, which blocks, or let the task run in the background and use NSFileHandle’s `readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify` with your file pipe and add an observer for the `NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification` notification.

Comment: I edited the code as in Question, still it is not blocking till the completion of NSTask execution.

Comment: The `waitUntilExit` blocks until the task is finished - is the task completing, or returning earlier than expected with an error?

Comment: `waitUntilExit` works, It blocks until task is finished.